# How do I prove a set is an orthonormal basis?

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ how do I go about proving it is an orthonormal basis in $L^2(\Omega)$? I understand easily how to show that it is orthonormal, but I am confused about how to prove it is a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Show that it is complete, that is, if $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ such that $f \perp a_n$ for all $n \in \mathbf N$, then $f = 0$.

Comment: Is there a theorem that says that will make it a basis? I am confused as to how that alone will push the result through.

Comment: For an orthonormal system one has: $\overline{\langle\mathcal{S}\rangle}=\mathcal{H}\iff\mathcal{S}^\perp=(0)$

Comment: Yes, there is. A complete orthonormal system in a Hilbert space is a basis.

Comment: @Freeze_S Changing to your terminology does not help, I think. To me a maximal orthonormal system is known as a *complete* orthonormal system.

Comment: @martini: Yep that is because of sloppy terminology, in general: An attempt to unravel that could be: Maximality ($\mathcal{S}^\perp=(0)$) vs. Completeness ($\overline{\langle\mathcal{S}\rangle}=\mathcal{H}$)

Answer (score 0):

**Theory**

Orthonormal Systems:
$$\overline{\langle\mathcal{S}\rangle}=\mathcal{H}\iff\mathcal{S}^\perp=(0)$$

Fourier Decomposition:
$$\varphi\in\overline{\langle\mathcal{S}\rangle}:\quad \varphi!=\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}}\langle\sigma,\varphi\rangle\sigma$$
*(Unique Decomposition!)*

**Problem**

> Check maximality:
>   $$\chi\in\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega):\quad\chi\perp\mathcal{S}\implies\chi=0$$
>   *(Approximation?)*